# How do I wrap the MouseEvent constructor from the EasleJS library in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I am porting same very handy Canvas and Animation libraries to GWT using the JSNI feature. Being the first library I am wrapping I could use a little assistance with this particular constructor:

```
/**
* This is passed as the parameter to onPress, onMouseMove, onMouseUp, onMouseDown, and onClick handlers on
* DisplayObject instances.
* By default, mouse events are disabled for performance reasons. In order to enabled them for a specified stage
* set mouseEventsEnabled to true on your stage instance.
* @class MouseEvent
* @constructor
* @param {String} type The event type.
* @param {Number} stageX The mouseX position relative to the stage.
* @param {Number} stageY The mouseY position relative to the stage.
* @param {DisplayObject} target The display object this event relates to.
* @param {MouseEvent} nativeEvent The native DOM event related to this mouse event.
**/
var MouseEvent = function(type, stageX, stageY, target, nativeEvent) {
  this.initialize(type, stageX, stageY, target, nativeEvent);
}
var p = MouseEvent.prototype;
```

You can view the entire class here: http://easeljs.com/docs/MouseEvent.js.html

My question is, how do I go about passing the event from GWT and successfully feed it to the JSNI constructor for this class?

FYI: I have forked Timknip's GWT port of Easeljs (0.2.1) and i'm updating it to include the latest Easel features (0.4.0). https://github.com/timknip/easel-gwt

EDIT: I think the native event would be a function you have written in Java, correct? Say you want to add a ONMOUSEUP event when you click the canvas somewhere, and the logic is kept in a function you wrote called "onClickSomeButton()", then you want to pass this method as a parameter in this constructor? I don't think Java can pass methods as parameters but isn't there some way to wrap this by extending some abstract GWT class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JavaScript functions are treated as objects, so you can simply pass it as an overlay type (extending `JavaScriptObject`), or as the underlying type (`JavaScriptObject` itself).

When encountering an issue like this, it's best to treat the handler (JavaScript event handler) - appearing as a function at the JavaScript layer - as an interface, defining one method at the Java layer, and wrapping a JSO underneath.

Please refer to [Google's docs on overlay types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCodingBasics.html#DevGuideOverlayTypes) for more on this.

Comment: Thank you so much. After examining the documentation I realize overlay types are exactly what I needed and the answer was right under my nose the whole time. Very much appreciated.. this had been a problem for me for sometime now. :)